# Hibernate - proper way to update collection which is mapped with cascading type all-delete-orphan

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, orm, mapping, all-delete-orphan

What would be the *right* and easy way to **update** the collection if it's mapped with **all-delete-orphan**  by it's "parent" object?
By updating I don't mean just adding/removing items from collection, but also updating the values of item properties (of course for those items that were previously in the collection).

Scenario is there's a `Parent` object that has a collections of `Child` objects and there's one form by which users can edit the Children collection - add/remove children but also **edit the children's properties** (on the same form).

Basically I want something like this:

```java
Parent parent = session.get(Parent.class, parentUI.getId());
parent.setChildren(parentUI.getChildren());  // parentUI is a DTO
session.saveOrUpdate(parent);
```

This doesn't work and I understand the reasons why, but as it seems to me this should be a very common situation when using hibernate and developing UI applications, so I'm seeking for a (by the book) solution.

I'm using hibernate 3.6.10 and XML based configuration.
Here's the relevant mapping (I'm using ArrayList for storing children collection):

```
<list name="children" cascade="all, delete-orphan">
    <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
    <list-index column="ordinal" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
</list>
```

If it matters child objects also have collections mapped in the same way but I don't think it's relevant since that is a problem equal to the one described.

Btw. I've lost a whole day on this and of course checked tens of very similar questions to this, but haven't found a reasonable solution or a pattern for solving this. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: try clearing the children list and then calling the 'setChildren' method

Comment: parent.setChildren(parentUI.getChildren());  If you want the detached objects to be saved, you can try merge() method. This might delete existing values, use it with caution.

Comment: Use saveOrUpdate when you pull the data from the db in the current sesssion and trying to update the values in the same session context.

Comment: @Zeus unfortunately however I try (merge or saveOrUpdate) I get "org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:".For which I do understand the reason why it is happening,

Comment: @Dav Blanked that won't work - NonUniqueObjectException is thrown since in the case of updating existing children there can be two instances with same identity - one loaded from DB, and the one from UI (it doesn't matter if the collection is cleaned first - child objects are still bound to Hibernate session)

Comment: I think you have to add more cascade types to update, add save_update / merge.

Comment: @Zeus I've tried that (ie. cascade="all, delete-orphan, merge") but with no success

Comment: Its wierd that it is not working, may be you have to query for all the children and save it without the involvement of the parent object. Last time when I was working with JPA, there was a property on the column annotation 'updatable' which used to stop all the updates that I do on the child object even when I have cascade set on it to all. You may want to check you config(On parent) for this type of setting.

Answer (score 1):

Well since I didn't find a *by the book* solution I've first solved this *manually* by creating a custom method on my parent object `parent.updateChildren(parentUI.getChildren())` which iterates through the old collection, compares it to the updated one from the UI and updates it manually. Needless to say it's far from ideal.

Then a colleague of mine (Zoran Regvart) gave me an witty idea (considering the technologies I'm using ie. Spring MVC) for improving things a little.
Idea is that, in case of submitting a form which updates the parent, before spring (web) binder does his work we can load the collection from the DB and set it to the command object (`parentUI`) thus "planting" it to be updated by the spring binder (in other words delegating the collection update process to him - thing that he does anyways).

Here is the (pseudo)code:

```
@ModelAttribute("parentUI")
public ParentUI initParentUI(HttpServletRequest p_request) {
    ParentUI parentUI = new ParentUI();
    String parentId = p_request.getParameter("id");
    if (parentId != null) { // indicates a form submit
        Parent parent = session.get(Parent.class, parentUI.getId());
        parentUI.setChildren(parent.getChildren());
    }
    return parentUI;
}
```

This way when spring binder does his work he will be updating the collection that is already bounded to Hibernate session.

This solution also isn't something that I'm too happy with and I haven't tested in many scenarios but for my current needs (for me) it's certainly somewhat of an improvement.

**UPDATE:** this workaround is convenient only in the case of **adding** new children or **editing** their properties. For cases of **deleting** children or **changing their order**  it better avoided since it ads complexity.